# Validate DBNULL throwing "operator cannot be applied to operands of type int and system dbnull"

Tags: c#, .net, strongly-typed-dataset

I thought it should be simple to validate but i failed to figure it by myself.

I am trying validate if the value have DBNULL or not

using

```
If((objAssessCircleRows[0].ClassValue) != System.DBNull.Value)
{
//do something

}
```

but it complains "operator cannot be applied to operands of type int and system dbnull".please some one guide me the right approach to validate DBNULL value

`objAssessCircleRows[0]` is a `DataRow`.

Comment: If `ClassValue` is an Int, it will *never* be DBNull.  Ever.

Comment: We really don't have enough context here. What's populating `objAssessCircleRows[0]`? If `ClassValue` is an `int` property, how did you expect it to have a value of `DBNull.Value`? You quite possibly want to make it an `int?` property instead, but then you'd be comparing against `null`, not `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: what is the type of objAssessCircleRows?  What is the type of ClassValue?

Comment: If `objAssessCircleRows[0]` is a `DataRow`, there's an `IsNull()` method on there.  If it's a typed dataset, I believe there are `ClassValueIsNull()` methods generated.  Dig around with Intellisense.

Comment: Appreciate all your help guys, objAssessCircleRows is a dataRow and  thanks Mike it works using ClassValueISNULL().

Comment: @Usher - Glad you got it working.  I added my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ClassValue` is an `Int32`, it will *never* be equal to `DBNull.Value` as there's no conversion between those two types.  I'm guessing you're getting an exception when you try to call the *getter* for `.ClassValue` though.

You'll want to use the `IsNull(string)` method to check first.  Something like:

```
if(objAssessCircleRows[0].IsNull("ClassValue")) // Column name from DataSet
{
   //do something
}
```

Also, if this was generated using *typed data sets*, there should also be generated matching *IsNull* methods to check for a Null value:

```
if(objAssessCircleRows[0].IsClassValueNull())
{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation that's more important to me,why i get that exception, thanks again.